# Is there a fast way to MOVE/update a bookmark?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

For example I am reading an online book, where each page is a URL. I only want to have the current page I am on bookmarked.

so I always have to delete the old bookmark then add the new bookmark.

This is kind of tedious and was wondering if there was a better way.

I am using chrome by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could Edit the bookmark URL and change the page number (I assume it appears in the URL).  It's probably quicker to add/delete though.

Answer (score 1):

- Bookmark like this:
  Drag the Bookmark Icon (the star before the address) to the Bookmarks Bar.
- Remove like this:
  Right click it and press the D key.

This should speed up the process a lot, I don't think that it can be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could go into your settings and create a new profile for the book you are reading and then change the on startup option to continue where I left off. Then when you want to read some more just click on the icon in the upper left of your browser window and open the books profile.